# How can I install PIL for python 2.7 32bit on windows?

Tags: python, windows, python-imaging-library

I recently got a new laptop, and I was in the process of transferring files back and forth when I remembered a game that I had been working on with python. However, I need PIL installed on my new laptop in order to get the game to work. I already have Python, Tkinter, and Pygame installed. But for the life of me, I cannot remember how I previously installed PIL on my old laptop and I was wondering how to do it. Although I have a 64-bit computer with Windows 10 and I am running python 2.7 32-bit on it, I haven't experienced any problems with similar specs. How can I do this? I have already tried installing PIP so that I can install PIL, but I have also concluded that that is a long and complicated process as well. Thanks in advance

specs --

model: Lenovo S145

processor: AMD A6-9225 (clocked at 2.6 Ghz)

ram: 8GB (6.89GB usable)

operating system: Windows 10 x64

version of python: Python 2.7.5 32-bit

Comment: What is long and complicated process? Have you not tried `pip install Pillow`? It should work if python is added to PATH.

Comment: I already have python added to path, and as far as I am aware, I don't think I have PIP installed (the installation of pip would be a long and complicated process if you're confused)

Comment: I dont understand what is so long about it. Have you not tried any tutorials yet? All you need to do is add python to PATH and pip will be available to use.(is what ive understood).

Comment: you see, most of the tutorials i have found just use "get-pip.py". While it may work for some, for me it has never worked at all. Even trying it now, it refuses to install.

Comment: Take a look [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ko9b_vC6XY0)

Comment: `pip` is installed with Python 2.7.  You don't need `get-pip.py`.  How are you determining it isn't installed or doesn't work?  Is `pip.exe` in your Python27\Scripts directory?

Comment: yes but my installation i have discovered does not have it.

Comment: The problems you're having may be related to the fact that Python 2.7 is past end of life and is no longer supported.

Comment: i am pretty sure that is all the errors I get when I install pip. Maybe there's a work around?

Comment: Re-install?  There is an option to install pip in the .exe installer.  I have 32-bit 2.7 installed, with pip, and with both PIL and Pillow installed, so I know it is (was) possible.  With 2.7 EOL, it's possible the pip wheels are no longer available.